# Eventlet wsgi server and time-consuming operations in requests

Tags: python, wsgi, eventlet

Let's assume we have a WSGI app which is hosted on an event-driven single-threaded server:

```
from eventlet import wsgi
import eventlet

def app(env, start_response):
    # IO opeartions here
    ...

wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8090)), app)
```

Within app function, some I/O operations such as reading files or DB access must be performed.

Now, when we perform IO operations in app, the server is effectively blocked and can't serve other clients.

**Q:** What are possible solutions to this problem? How can I get Eventlet wsgi server perform time-consuming operations while not getting blocked?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: use mysqldb/psycopg or `eventlet.import_patched()` pure python DB drivers; `tpool.execute()` for files and everything else.

Try to mend your thought process into separating operations which could be converted to cooperation with Eventlet and those for which it is impossible. Cooperation here means breaking into "execute code" - "wait for result" parts and providing notification mechanism when result is ready. Main notification mechanism for Eventlet is file descriptors.

So everything that waits for file descriptor is a candidate to be green (not blocking). Most importantly, it affects all network IO. If your blocking function is written in pure Python, just use `import_patched(module_name)` to modify its `socket` and other references to Eventlet green version. `mysqldb` and `psycopg2` are special cases of C extension modules made cooperative thanks for explicit support from their authors. Everything else blocking in non Python code - your option is OS threads.

Unfortunately, waiting on actual disk files is full of quirks, so I recommend using OS threads and we have built-in thread pool to support that. Convert `blocking_fun(filepath, something_else)` to `eventlet.tpool.execute(blocking_fun, filepath, something_else)` and it doesn't block everything. Check tpool documentation for details.

If you can, reengineer whole application into blocking and non-blocking processes and have them communicate via sockets. This is hard from code rewriting point of view, but very simple for runtime, debugging; robust and fail-proof design.